# Debug: Heroku Error but no error on local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

My app is working locally, however, for some reason part of the app isn't working on Heroku. I have checked the `heroku logs --tail`, however, there aren't any errors appearing. It's just showing the default 404 page.

Are there any options to debug this issue?

Comment: did you add root url?

Comment: @uzaif Whereabouts?

Comment: in your routes file which located under config

Comment: heroku  logs -n 500. check ur logs there must be some error

Comment: Found `Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)`. How do I go about fixing it? I have already restarted the app.

Comment: Guys, it looks like I found the issue. I am using Carrierwave to upload images and it looks like the memory exceeded on a particular image. I had to delete one of the latest records and everything is in working order again.

Comment: Have you ran "heroku run rake db:migrate" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looked like CarrierWave couldn't handle one of the files being uploaded. Perhaps it was too big? Thus, I deleted one of the latest records added to the table.